# R algorithm or function to train using a LogLoss error

Tags: r, predictive-models, log-loss

Is there a way to train a RandomForest, GBM or other classification model using a LogLoss error measure?

So far I have trained it, but I get an OOB error rate. From there I calculate the sigmoid and use that as my probability in order to minimize the LogLoss... but I have a hard time to find literature or examples on how to optimize an algorithm training using log loss.

Here is the LogLoss function in R:

```
llfun <- function(actual, prediction) {
    epsilon <- .000000000000001
    yhat <- pmin(pmax(prediction, epsilon), 1-epsilon)
    logloss <- -mean(actual*log(yhat)
                     + (1-actual)*log(1 - yhat))
    return(logloss)
}
```

Comment: @mbq Actually the code came from here: https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/LogarithmicLoss So I cannot change it.

Comment: Well, apparently Kaggle guys don't know R (; Calling rep on a single number is purely redundant, like adding 0 or multiplying by 1.